# How to make auto reset page when search in React (Inertia.js) with debounce

Tags: reactjs, search, pagination, inertiajs, debouncing

Actually this is working fine for search, load, and page ([show identities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhh11.png)) . The problem is when I open page 4 and search somethin, it will show empty data ([search=mars on page four](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03Wjv.png)) because the data is small so it only show on the first page, so I need to go to the first page to show the data ([search=mars on first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQo1z.png)).

here is my controller

```
    public $loadDefault = 5;
    
    public function index(Request $request){
        $users = User::query()
                    ->when($request->search, 
                        fn ($q, $key) => $q
                            ->where('name', 'like', "%{$key}%")
                            ->orWhere('email', 'like', "%{$key}%")
                        );

        return Inertia('Identities/Index', [
            'users' => (UserResource::collection($users->paginate($request->load)->withQueryString()))->additional([
               'filter' => [
                    'search' => $request->search ?? '',
                    'page' => $request->page ?? '',
                    'load' => $request->load ?? $this->loadDefault
                ],
                'attributes' => [
                    'per_page' => 10,
                    'total' => User::count(),
                ]
            ]),
        ]);
    }
```

here is my page (index.jsx)

```
import Table from "@/Components/Table";
import AuthenticatedLayout from "@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout";
import { Head, Link } from "@inertiajs/react";
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { debounce, pickBy } from "lodash";
import { router } from "@inertiajs/react";

export default function Index({ auth, ...props }) {
    const { data: people, meta, filter, attributes } = props.users;

    const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState(filter.search);

    const reload = useCallback(
        debounce((q) => {
            router.get(
                route("identities.index"),
                pickBy({
                    load: filter.load,
                    search: q,
                    page: filter.page,
                }),
                {
                    preserveState: true,
                    preserveScroll: true,
                }
            );
        }, 500),
        []
    );

    useEffect(() => reload(keyword), [keyword]);

    console.log(people);
    return (
        <AuthenticatedLayout
            user={auth.user}
            header={
                <h2 className="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
                    Users Index
                </h2>
            }
        >
            <Head title="Users" />

            <div className="py-12 mx-auto max-w-[80rem]">
                <div className="p-4 lg:p-6 h-full flex-col flex gap-y-5">
                    <div className="flex items-center justify-end">
                        <div className="w-1/2">
                            <input
                                type={"text"}
                                name="search"
                                id="search"
                                value={keyword}
                                onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
                                className="form-text w-full"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="w-full rounded-lg border border-gray-300 overflow-hidden cursor-not-allowed shadow-sm">
                        <Table>
                            <Table.Thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <Table.Th>#</Table.Th>
                                    <Table.Th>username</Table.Th>
                                    <Table.Th>name</Table.Th>
                                    <Table.Th>email</Table.Th>
                                    <Table.Th>address</Table.Th>
                                    <Table.Th>joined</Table.Th>
                                    <Table.Th className={"sr-only"}>
                                        aksi
                                    </Table.Th>
                                </tr>
                            </Table.Thead>
                            <Table.Tbody>
                                {people.map((person, index) => (
                                    <tr
                                        key={index}
                                        className="bg-white border-b
                                    hover:bg-slate-500 hover:bg-opacity-5 even:bg-slate-50"
                                    >
                                        <Table.Td>{meta.from + index}</Table.Td>
                                        <Table.Td>{person.username}</Table.Td>
                                        <Table.Td>{person.name}</Table.Td>
                                        <Table.Td>{person.email}</Table.Td>
                                        <Table.Td>{person.address}</Table.Td>
                                        <Table.Td>{person.joined}</Table.Td>
                                        <Table.Td>
                                            <div className="w-fit">
                                                <Link
                                                    href={"#"}
                                                    className="inline-flex bg-gray-50 hover:bg-white hover:drop-shadow text-xs font-normal px-1.5 py-1.5 rounded-md border border-blue-400"
                                                >
                                                    <svg
                                                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                                        className="w-5 h-5 stroke-[1.25]"
                                                        width={24}
                                                        height={24}
                                                        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                                        strokeWidth="2"
                                                        stroke="currentColor"
                                                        fill="none"
                                                        strokeLinecap="round"
                                                        strokeLinejoin="round"
                                                    >
                                                        <path
                                                            stroke="none"
                                                            d="M0 0h24v24H0z"
                                                            fill="none"
                                                        ></path>
                                                        <path d="M4 20h4l10.5 -10.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 -4 -4l-10.5 10.5v4"></path>
                                                        <path d="M13.5 6.5l4 4"></path>
                                                    </svg>
                                                </Link>
                                            </div>
                                        </Table.Td>
                                    </tr>
                                ))}
                            </Table.Tbody>
                        </Table>
                    </div>
                    <ul className="flex items-center gap-x-1 mt-5 text-sm">
                        {meta.links.map((item, index) => (
                            <Link
                                key={index}
                                href={item.url}
                                className={`${
                                    item.url == null
                                        ? "text-gray-500 cursor-default"
                                        : ""
                                } flex items-center justify-center rounded-md border bg-white px-3 py-2
                                `}
                            >
                                {item.label}
                            </Link>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </AuthenticatedLayout>
    );
}
```

**How to make auto reset on the first page when I search something?**

I try to edit this function but I can't go to another page..

`page: q ? 1 : filter.page`

It alway return first page when I search something..

Help me.. Thank you..